# What are the risks if a weak ciphers are accepted by a technology that uses SSL

Tags: encryption, tls

The [TLSSLed tool](http://blog.taddong.com/2013/02/tlssled-v13.html) found that the host that I use has SSL connection that accepts 8 different TLSv1 and SSLv3 ciphers that are weak by their length (40 bits).

How can an attacker exploit this fact?

Answer (score 0):

There is a few "popular" attacks on SSL. They were discussed i.e. in [How SSL works](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/20833/32976), section "How to crack SSL". In addition, you can read more about [BREACH](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/08/gone-in-30-seconds-new-attack-plucks-secrets-from-https-protected-pages/) attack, which was discovered in 2013.